# Google Rich Snippet on Real Estate Site

Tags: google, google-search, rich-snippets, structured-data

I would like to know what would be the Structured Data Mark-up that will lead too this Rich Snippet:
[image]

I am particularly interested on the list of link under the First Rich Snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not [Rich Snippets](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/).

The first snippet has [one-line sitelinks](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/04/one-line-sitelinks.html), the second snippet has [breadcrumbs](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the **[link](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/)** from official documentation.

To make your pages eligible for Rich Snippets in search results, add structured data of the appropriate type to your content. Make sure to comply with any policies that each type has regarding Rich Snippet display.

Comment: it doesn't show on how to create with that kind of snippet.

Comment: http://www.vervesearch.com/blog/a-guide-to-rich-snippets-schema-and-microdata/